# mongodb + mongoose MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my first mongo-db application to server :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const URI = "";

mongoose
    .connect(URI,{useUnifiedTopology:true,useNewUrlParser:true})
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("Encountered error...");
        console.log("error : "+err);
    });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

But it gives me **error : MongooseServerSelectionError: connection  to 35.223.140.90:27017 closed**.

I have white listed my IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to whitelist the IP address on ATLAS

1. Go to Network Access Panel
2. Click Add IP Address
3. add 0.0.0.0/0 (Allows all ips)
4. save

This is for development only, for prod, you can add your server ip.

Comment: thanks, but why this 0.0.0.0/0 works, may I know the reason ?

Comment: It allows all IP address to connect, that's why more secure way would be whitelisting your own IPs.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have this line in your app.js `app.use(cors())`?

Try to delete this line and delete everything that involves cors.

If this don't work, check your IP Whitelist inside Network Access in MongoDB Atlas and add your current IP or write this 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all IPs.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete all the old IP address and add a new one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32282722)